# Back Button Issue

Tags: apex, case, browser

We have a Custom object (Contribution) and it is exposed a related list of Case.

This contibution object record needs to be integrated with another system.

Even after successful handshake from the other system,  the status on the contribution record is displaying as "Processing" in the related list but if we click on the URL (C-1234 the name field) of the Contribution record it takes us to standard layout where the status is "Successful".

But when we press the back button from the browser it still showing as "Processing".

Has anyone faced any issue like this ?

Comment: It might be the cache of your browser. What happens if you click back and RELOAD the page?

Comment: @Bachovski - Yep that was it !. Please put this as answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely the browser cache. If you reload the page it should show the correct status. It's nothing to do with Salesforce. Depending on the browser there might be cache settings where you can disable it and you should be good.